# One month forward in my xAxis

Tags: php, json, highcharts

i'm using Highstock charts with php but i have a strange problem which happens in my chart, X axis is one month forward !
my data is something like this

```
...
[Date.UTC(2016,01,11,17,21),24],
[Date.UTC(2016,01,11,17,51),24.1],
[Date.UTC(2016,01,11,18,21),24.1],
[Date.UTC(2016,01,11,18,51),24.4],]
```

but on the chart .. the month is "Feb" instead of Jan !
is there any sitting to do for that ?

Comment: Javascript starts indexing months from 0 to 11 instead of 1 to 12 as it is in PHP. So in this case, 1 is actually a February and January would be 0

Answer (score 1):

According to Date.UTC documentation, months are indexed from 0 not 1.

```
Date.UTC(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]])
```

> month
>
> An integer between 0 and 11 representing the month.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC